# Relationship between flux, circulation, mass, and line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculus 3.  Ok, I am having some trouble understanding exactly what is going on with these concepts.  I think I get that line integrals represent the amount of work done moving a particle around a field, and that flux is the tendency of a particle to get pushed across a boundary (although not exactly the work DONE pushing that particle). Then there is curl and divergence.

These concepts are all presented together, and the formulas/theorems shouldn't be too hard to memorize, but I am having HUGE trouble distinguishing them because I don't understand what these concepts REPRESENT, i.e., WHY integrate the dot product of F and dr?  For example, revolutions of solids was the distance from one boundary to the other used as a radius in the area of a circle, integrated from a lower boundary to an upper boundary.  Easy to conceptualize.  Can anyone break down the above concepts in a similar fashion?

Thanks in advance.